# Show details of current user in different table from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my database, there are two tables. Both have a username column. `Table A` is stores user information, and `Table B` is stores users' reservations. In my page, there will be a drop down menu that will retrieve `BookingID`s for the currently logged in user. How should they be retrieved?

To help you understand, this should give you an idea of what I mean.

User X login,
`If User X(Table A) = User X(Table B)`
Then dropdown1 shows `BookingID` of User X from `Table B`.

I am sorry I don't provide any code because I really don't have any idea how to do it. Any answers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using anything like entity framework? If so, there are some pretty easy solutions revolving around that. Otherwise, you can manually create a datatable from your pulled data.

Answer (score 2):

This will list all `BookingID`s of users that are in both tables:

```
select b.BookingID 
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.username = b.username
```

Comment: In this case, should I create a new table for join?

Comment: Joins are totally normal in SQL. You don't have to avoid them except you have serious performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL

```
SELECT
   //TABLE_A.required_cols
   //TABLE_B.required_cols
FROM
   TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.USER_ID = TABLE_B.USER_ID
```

**Note:**: Here I've assumed that both tables have a column called `USER_ID` that match for the same user, say X

Answer (score 0):

Create a data table and then populate it create the table as follows:

```
Private Function CreateDataSource() As DataTable
    'creates the columns for the datatable 
    Dim dt As New DataTable 'create new datatable

    'add appropriate columns to the table
    Dim colImage As New DataColumn("Field1", GetType(Boolean))
    colImage.DefaultValue = bShowExtraInfo
    dt.Columns.Add(colImage)
    dt.Columns.Add("Field2", GetType(String))

    Return dt 'return the table
End Function
```

and then use it in your code like so:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = CreateDataSource() 'create the data table
    Dim dr As DataRow
        For Each x In y 'cycle through x and add to table
                dr("Field1") = tableAvalue
                dr("Field2") = tableBvalue
                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            End If
        Next
    gvEverything.DataSource = dt
    gvEverything.DataBind()
```

Comment: Can pls provide in C#? Would appreciate that :)

Comment: c# isn't my forte', but basically, just change the stuff around. Take the dim off the front, and put the type in front of the variable name, for instance instead of dim dt as datatable, it's datatable dt; I think (I might be wrong) change most of the () for [] but you might have to do some comparisons to stuff on the internet.